# writing jest test cases for util classes

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs

in Vue , I have a util class where i abstracted the axios invocation and bit of logic..

import Axios from 'axios'..the code almost looks like this

```
export default {
  getStudentNumber (name) {
    Axios.post('myurl', { studentName: name }).then({
      //some logic
      //return
    })
  }
}
```

This is being invoked from my Vue class... I wrote jest test cases for Vue and I mocked the Axios in that...But is there a way to write separate test cases for this service class ? How to write it? Becuase I have a lot of logic in this... I am using jest

Comment: _"is there a way to write separate test cases for this service class"_ yes. Was that all you wanted to know?

Comment: No..how yo write it

Comment: Test it method by method. The rest depends on your class. What did you try and what did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the test for your service like this:

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import myService from './myService';

jest.mock('axios');

describe('my service', () => {
  describe('getStudentNumber', () => {
    it('should call Axios.post with myurl and studentName', () => {
      myService.getStudentNumber('mock name');
      expect(Axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myurl', { studentName: 'mock name' })
    });

    describe('given a successful response', () => {
      beforeAll(() => {
        // setup mock for successful flow
        Axios.post.mockResolvedValue({ responseMock });
      });

      it('should do this', () => {
        const result = myService.getStudentNumber();
        // describe the expected result 
        expect(result).toEqual({ ...... });
      });
    });

    describe('given an error', () => {
      beforeAll(() => {
        // setup mock for non-successful flow
        Axios.post.mockRejectedValue(new Error('some mock error'));
      });

      it('should do that', () => {
        const result = myService.getStudentNumber();
        // describe the expected result 
        expect(result).toEqual({ ...... });
      });
    });
  });
});
```